# string contains only alphabets

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java programming and I need help.
Create a table of String and the user gives the size. Subsequently, the user gives  String. I want to print the characters but without the characters which are not letters of the alphabet (eg. java!4 --> java,  ja/?,.va --> java)

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

String[] x = new String[size];
int size;
String str= "";

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.print("Give me size: ");
size = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());


    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    System.out.print("Give me a String: ");
    str = input.readLine();
    x[i]=str;
    }


}
```

I am looking on the internet for this code:

```
    if (str.matches("[a-zA-Z]")){
System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're new to programming and don't want to involve in the RegEx world (yet), you can create a method that returns a `String` with letters only:

```
public String getStringOfLettersOnly(String s) {
    //using a StringBuilder instead of concatenate Strings
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            //adding data into the StringBuilder
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    //return the String contained in the StringBuilder
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a very simple regular expression:  `s/[^A-z]//g`.  This will substitute nothing for all characters in the string which aren't in the range `A-z`, which encapsulates all letters (upper and lowercase).  Simply do `new_string = old_string.replaceAll("[^A-z]", "");`.

Comment: In response to the suggested edit, eliminating ``new_string`` and ``old_string`` and using a single variable:  including the two variables makes the intent clearer, and it is often preferable to treat values like this as immutable rather than reassigning to the same variable multiple times, even in production code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a `string` has only `alphabets` with regex.
below is the sample code

```
String word = "java";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compiles("[a-zA-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
System.out.println(pattern.find());
```

Or you can use `String.matches(regex)` from [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).
You can read more about [REGEX in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) here.